# I don't have the "edit enterprise library configuration" option in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, enterprise-library

I installed Enterprise Library 5.0 and, in context menu, when I click at app.config in project in Visual Studio, I don't have the option:

> Edit enterprise library configuration

My coworker has, so it's weird, because we have installed the same version.

But we have option

> Edit enterprise library V5 configuration

But I need the first option. Does anyone know the problem ?

Comment: I am confused on your issue.  Do you want the first or second option?

Comment: second option I have, but I havent first option which I must to have.

Comment: You probably want to remove that plugin. It has caused me nothing but headaches, and tends to make VS crawl to a halt, especially when using WF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntLib V5 can run side-by-side with previous versions of EntLib. This was done to allow people to evaluate V5 without impacting their current dev environment that may use previous versions of EntLib.

If you see the context menu item "Edit enterprise library configuration", that's for EntLib v4.0 or 4.1 and the menu item "Edit enterprise library V5 configuration" is clearly for V5. Makes sense?

In a SxS scenario, you can have both menu items available.

Answer (score 1):

In v5 you will only this option "**Edit enterprise library V5 configuration**". They have changed the way you used to configure blocks.

Comment: He has 4.1 installed :/ Thank you for help :)